# Notes In Published Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

I've developed a website for our active adult association.  I upload an Excel spreadsheet to Google Drive.  It has notes attached to cells.  The notes display fine in the converted version in Drive.  After I "publish" it to the web, copy the address and add the spreadsheet to my website, the notes no longer work as they did a month ago.  It's not possible to hover the cursor over a cell to see the note.  The cell has the note Id number in it and the notes are listed at the bottom of the spreadsheet.

I downloaded the spreadsheet that worked last month and the same thing happened so I'm sure it is not the spreadsheet.

Has there been a change to how notes are displayed or is there now a problem with Google spreadsheets?

Comment: I still do not see notes in published spreadsheets :(

Answer (score 2):

The actual version of Google spreadsheets doesn't publish the notes. This "unsupported feature" isn't yet documented in the Docs editors help.

**References**
[Check out the new Google Sheets - Docs editores Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3541068?hl=en)